# How to add model entity property in WCF RIA service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, silverlight

I'm developing silverlight app with WCF Ria service. I'm using MS SQL database and Entity Framework as ORM framework (Database first method). Model with domain service are in separate project - App1.Data. Silverlight and generated model proxy classes are in App1 project.

I want to add property to model entity class EntityClass to get this property on client side.

So I did it that way - added this class to project App1.Data:

```
public partial class EntityClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<EntityClass2> PropertyName {get; set;}
}
```

After rebuilding EntityClass proxy on client side doesn't have this new property. 
Where is my mistake?

Comment: I can't remember if it is VS or ReSharper that greys out the word `partial` and gives a tooltip of 'partial used for a class with only one part', if it doesn't detect any other partial definitions for this class. All parts of partial classes must be defined in the same assembly, so maybe that's your problem?

Comment: Both parts are in the same assembly App1.Data.Models.

Comment: If this is going to be a client side only property, why the [DataMember] attribute? It won't be serialised as part of the DataContract with WCF.